# Reg Ex: Remove superfluous zeros and decimal point at the end of a number

Tags: javascript, regex

From a datasource I'm getting many numbers that need formatting before presenting in a browser.

Some of the numbers appear with trailing zeros, and some of the numbers appear with a trailing decimal point with nothing afterwards.

Here are examples of what I've been trying to achieve with Javascript's RegEx implementation:

```
130.0000     = 130
132.0050     = 132.005
16.9000      = 16.9
140000000.00 = 140000000
132.         = 132
89.0         = 89
90.0         = 90
9000.00      = 9000
99.0         = 99
99.00500     = 99.005
70           = 70 //fail, as it matches the zeros at the end if there's no decimal point
700          = 700 //fail, as it matches the zeros at the end if there's no decimal point
```

The following RegEx matches everything correctly except the last two tests where any zeros before the decimal point are also matched:

```
[\.0]0*$
```

Any help with what's now giving me a headache would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks in advance...

Comment: `[\.0]` means *either a `.` or a `0`*. You probably meant `(\.0)`.

Comment: I think, if you go the regex route, you'd have to use two seperate regexes. `\.0*$` to match trailing zeros, including the decimal point, and something like `\.\d*?(0*)$` to capture trailing zeros (in a capture group this time) but only following a decimal point. Combining the two seems quite complicated, and you might be better off with a different approach.

Comment: @SpoonMeiser: Not that complicated: `\.0*(?!\d)|(\.\d*?)0+\b` and replace with `$1`.  But the accepted answer is still better.

Comment: @AlanMoore, very impressive. Many thanks for your answer. Whilst I agree that the accepted answer is the best solution I was scratching my head trying to work out the RegEx.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most robust function that will take all of your inputs and trim them is [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat):

```js
const values = [
  '130.0000',
  '132.0050',
  '16.9000',
  '140000000.00',
  '132.',
  '89.0',
  '90.0',
  '9000.00',
  '99.0',
  '99.00500',
  '70',
  '700'
];

values.map(parseFloat).forEach(it => console.log(it));
```

You can then use any of the `Number` methods to get a specific precision, round, reformat, etc.

While regular expressions can do [many unholy things](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/129032), sometimes there's a function that just works.

Comment: `values.map(Number);` is sufficient

Comment: @Tushar using the `Number` constructor has different behavior to `parseInt` or `parseFloat` in some cases and using it as the callback to a map is unclear, at best.

Comment: `values.map(parseFloat)` is sufficient. The arrow function isn't necessary.

Comment: @wcarroll fixed. I always forget `parseFloat` can't take any other args.